# Setting up in-App Purchase to debug code IOS

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to learn how to include in-App purchases in my app.  I currently only need an iAP that allows me to upgrade app from the free version to a full version.  All the code is already included for the full version just disabled unless the iAP is purchased.  I am following some tutorials and documentation from Apple that shows a screen in iTunes Connect/My Apps that has in-App Purchases in the top bar and then goes on to ask a bunch of questions.

What I see under iTunes Connect/My Apps does not contain in-App Purchases but does contain an entry entitled "Features" and under this there is an in-App Purchases on the left side and when I click on this I get the cryptic message:

"Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.

Once your binary has been uploaded and your first In-App Purchase has been submitted for review, additional In-App Purchases can be submitted using the table below."

My iAP has zero size since it is only to see it has been purchased or not and I haven't even gotten to the point of submitting builds to Itunes.  Again, I am trying to learn how to do this and the learning curve seems to be a step function.

So the question is, is there any resource out there that will help me figure out how get past this?

The Apple documents were from Sept. 2015 so this may be new for IOS9 but i need a "how To" to be able to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Basically, the message you are seeing is just for release build. However when you're trying to test your features of iAPs you have to create a sandbox tester under the Users and Roles accounts. This tester account will the be able to buy the iAPs for free while testing. Then, once you have created the tester, on the screen you were where it tells you:

> Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version.

just click the + button here:
[image: screenshot]

Then you'll be taken to this page:
[image: page]

Where you will select consumable so that the User has to only pay once, and then you will be taken to the final set-up page that looks something like that:

[image: page3]

From here you can just follow your tutorial to complete the project. For your convenience, I will attach a great tutorial from Appcoda [here](http://www.appcoda.com/in-app-purchase-tutorial/), that is a great way to get up and running with iAPs

Hope that helps, Julian.

Comment: Thanks Julian E., This fixed the problem.  Figures it would be something non-sequitor like that.